# Webpage change monitoring

Tags: python, html

I want to monitor a announcement webpage, so that when a new announcement comes in, I can execute tasks as quickly as possible. Currently I'm using python with requests package:

```
allText = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
```

and then find the first occurrence of the text with a particular header corresponding to an article item:

```
ind = allText.find(''<li class="article-list-item">''); allText = allText[ind:]; ind = allText.find(''</a>''); allText = allText[0:ind]
```

I'm repeating the command (i.e. refreshing the page) every ~1.5 seconds.

The problems are:

1. it's not fast enough. It typically takes more than 3 seconds for my programme to detect it after a new webpage appears. I guess the text finding is taking up too much time. Is there a faster way?
2. on some website, the articles are concealed and the requests command does not return anything even though the browser can still see it. An example source code of the webpage is:

   `<div data-app="recent-activity" data-url="/hc/api/internal/recent_activities">/div>`

How should I scrape this kind of page please?

Comment: I think there are 2 problems, One) is the code that you are using to parse the response - Please can you include it.
Two) If you are frequently polling another site, your connections may be throttled and eventually blocked, to retain bandwidth for real users.
You could consider doing a `Head` request, and work out if there is any change of the page, depending on their headers alone. This will mitigate your appearance of being an attacker. Only when the `Head` indicates that there is a change, should you get the content,

Comment: Finally, for your follow on question, which should be separate, you need to use an http client class that can execute the site's Javascript. Please bear in mind that you are using up lots of someone else's resources to do this monitoring.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts thank you so much for your help. The codes I'm using are a simple string find function to truncate the whole text and get the article title, e.g. `ind = allText.find(''<li class="article-list-item">''); allText = allText[ind:]; ind = allText.find(''</a>''); allText = allText[0:ind]`  If I request `Head` , do I still occupy other people's resources please? So the codes in the 2nd problem is Javascript?

Comment: Please include your code in the question, so that it's not buried in the comments. Every time you make a request to a web server, you are using bandwidth. However a Head request will generate much less data, and may include data which lets you know when a page was last changed. You'll have to read up on the http headers, to make the most of them.

Comment: I see, thank you! @Dragonthoughts